# Highlighting multiple text formik Inputs control border with RED when ERROR

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I have 2 formik text fields on the react `xyz.tsx` page. It is firing the relevant error message properly on the page but I want to highlight the border of the both text fields in red (as when one field validation failed). How would I do that?

Here is my yup validation schema

```
export const requiredPoints = yup
  .array()
  .of(
    yup.object({
      number1: yup.number().typeError('Must be a number').nullable(true),
      number2: yup.number().typeError('Must be a number').nullable(true),

      number1OrNumber2Error: yup.number().when(['number1', 'number2'], {
        is: (number1: any, number2: any) => isBlank(number1) && isBlank(number2),
        then: yup.number().required('A point must have at least a Number 1 or Number 2 value entered.'),
        otherwise: yup.number(),
      }),
    }),
  )
  .nullable(true);
```

**

> xyz.tsx

**,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Label } from '@fluentui/react';
-----

interface PointProps {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  label?: string;
  required?: boolean;
}

export const Point: React.FC<PointProps> = (props) => {

  return (
    <>
      <div className="style-1">
        <NumberField name={props.name + '.number1'} label="Number 1" />
      </div>
      <div className="style-1">
        <NumberField name={props.name + '.number2'} label="Number 2" />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please show your jsx code. Remove all `onBlur` function. that will do

Comment: Thanks and xyz.tsx page looks like above.